# I'm getting "Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/:" When attempting to run my Flutter app on Chrome

Tags: flutter, google-chrome, http-status-code-503

Here is the full error:

```
Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"
```

I have tried clearing browsing data as suggested online but I can't seem to find any other guidance. Help much appreciated.

**Expected**

I was expecting for the app to launch in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same in a react app upgraded to use vite ( you can get skeleton by `yarn create vite repro -- --template react-ts` )

The problem was because in my older app I missed `index.html` file that in turn contains the reference to the module "/src/index.tsx".

Answer (score 8):

try to run `npm start` in terminal

then start debugging `f5` in vscode

Comment: Works perfectly as expected!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Sinos Gray! Once I saw this, I realized all I needed to do was to add a preLaunchTask setting to the configuration in launch.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
    },
  ]
}
```

Now it runs via run (`F5`)

Hope this helps!!! :)