I encountered a problem in installing Laravel Vscode
"npm start
Debugger attached.
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?       
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:   
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! "

"Waiting for the debugger to disconnect..."

I run npm start and get these errors in windows.
I did npm start and f5 and I also got the error "Cannot connect to localhost"
Could not read source map for chrome-error://chromewebdata/: Unexpected 503 response from chrome-error://chromewebdata/neterror.rollup.js.map: Unsupported protocol "chrome-error:"

A bit of care and attention while creating your post please.

Please Never post images of or off site links to Code/Data/Error Messages.
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

What is npm start supposed to do?

@brombeer https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-start all yours means nothing to me, I have never used it

It needs to run the laravel file. I did this because it was done that way in similar examples.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77859610/im-getting-could-not-read-source-map-for-chrome-error-chromewebdata-when?newreg=945b8406e66347948a687380ba2432ba

Never used npm start (with Laravel) either, according to the documentation it's npm install then npm run dev

what should i do

you should not use npm start for Laravel project, you would use npm install to download needed assests defined for project and after that npm run devto compile js and css file needed for laravel app.
npm start is used specificaly for npm projects like Angular.
Please check package.json file (scripts part) in your laravel app, it should look something like this:

That script part will list all available commands for your current laravel project. Again npm part is related to the frontend side of your project. After you are done with npm commands and you are serving your app via herd or artisan:serve you can try to open your app in browser of your choosing.
